# Box.com authorization page in IFrame is not displaying when the user is authenticated in a separate browser window

Tags: iframe, authorization, box-api

Our web app uses Box.com authorization like documented here: https://developers.box.com/oauth/ . We open 
https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=zggod7aqblw0n7qsmn7zoztzwt979al3&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8888%2Fintegration-callback%3FserviceType%3Dbox
in an IFrame and it normally works fine.
But if the user goes to www.box.com in a separate browser window and logs in there, displaying  the authorization page in our IFrame stops working because Box.com's response loaded to the IFrame contains "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" HTTP header.
Switching from an IFrame to a separate browser window is not an option for us. How else can we work around the issue?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be calling that link in an iframe, you should be re-directing the user directly to the box.com site, and box.com will redirect back to your site afterwards.

Comment: That's not a good option for us because our app is not just a web site but a heavy GWT application with a lot of context that will be lost in the sequence of redirects.

Comment: I'm running into this same problem. If my app opens an action in a popup, Box will not allow me to redirect the user to an authentication page in the popup. It's really irritating that we have to build our apps to run in a frame, but Box refuses to run in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I ended up with was displaying a message next to the IFrame that if Box.com didn't open and you are logged in Box.com in another browser window then please log out from Box.com in that window and try again.
Attempting to determine automatically if Box.com didn't load failed due to browsers' cross host origin access restrictions (that prevented me from accessing the IFrame's DOM).